# Distribute object instances at every vertex

Tags: instances, geometry-nodes

Can I distribute object instances at every vertex? I tried with the new geometry nodes but it only distirbutes randomly (see screenshot).
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the Point Distribute node. Just use the Point Instance Node.